# Convert ICS format into valid JS format

Tags: javascript, icalendar

I asking about converting date from ICAl which is read ICS file from the calendar to valid Javascript format
the date returns from ICAL is **20200428T130000**
I need this format to be valid in javascript I tried the next method

```
$date = new Date('20200428T130000');
```

and I got the next error

```
Invalid Date
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: one way is to transform it first to `2020-04-28T13:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with with [moment.js library](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
const moment = require('moment')

console.log(moment('20200428T130000').toISOString())
// 2020-04-28T13:00:00.000Z
```